# Can Someone Tell Me Why I Am Getting This Error While Compiling raylib for android

Tags: android, c++, c, compiler-errors, raylib

So, i Was compiling raylib for android with [This](https://github.com/raysan5/raylib/wiki/Working-for-Android) and i linked all androidhome,jdk,ndk etc. correctly (I think) And This Error Log's Out In The Terminal Even When I Use A Template Project.

```
PS D:\Dev\VISUAL studio PROJECT\RaylibTest> mingw32-make PLATFORM=PLATFORM_ANDROID
mingw32-make -f Makefile.Android 
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/Dev/VISUAL studio PROJECT/RaylibTest'
if not exist android.game mkdir android.game 
/usr/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
mingw32-make[1]: *** [Makefile.Android:144: create_temp_project_dirs] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/Dev/VISUAL studio PROJECT/RaylibTest' 
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:374: all] Error 2
PS D:\Dev\VISUAL studio PROJECT\RaylibTest>
```

If You Need Any Other Information Please Tell Me

Comment: Might not be the reason but - avoid spaces in pathnames most tools can't cope.

Comment: You're getting this error because of a typo in this project's Makefile. You will need to fix it in order to build this.

Comment: ok lemme try but there shouldn't be spaces in the makefile of template projects

Comment: @DG58 spaces here `D:\Dev\VISUAL studio PROJECT\RaylibTest`

Comment: nope didn't work

Comment: I would take my chances with the CMake build system that comes with that library, rather than a platform-specific makefile.

Comment: ok am i getting this right ?

1. First, i have to link the library in cmake
2. Then, i have to compile the project with Cmake and that lib

But, then how do i make it so that cmake outputs the file as a .apk because i want to build it for android

Comment: so can someone tell me which genrator i should use for this i haven't used cmake befor